# How to print binary tree?

Tags: c, struct, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I created a program that basically has a binary tree and I can delete/insert nodes in it. I can calculate its traversals too, but I want to print the tree in a real form. What I mean. 
The program now prints : 1 2 3 4

I want to print:

```
       1    
     /   \
    2     3  
   /   
  4
```

This is certainly doable, but I am short on time. Please provide a solution to this problem. (yes I know requesting a solution is a lot).
In my code, I commented the lines, where the functions that print the result are being called. The comment looks like this"// i want to print this as a tree"
those are the lines in which the tree is calculated and printed. All I want is to make them so they print a real tree.

My code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
struct node1
{
    int key1;
    struct node1 *left1, *right1;
};

// A utility function to create a new BST node1
struct node1 *newnode1(int item)
{
    struct node1 *temp1 =  (struct node1 *)malloc(sizeof(struct node1));
    temp1->key1 = item;
    temp1->left1 = temp1->right1 = NULL;
    return temp1;
}

// A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST
void inorder(struct node1 *root1)
{
    if (root1 != NULL)
    {
        inorder(root1->left1);
        printf("%d ", root1->key1);
        inorder(root1->right1);
    }
}

/* A utility function to insert1 a new node1 with given key1 in BST */
struct node1* insert1(struct node1* node1, int key1)
{
    /* If the tree is empty, return a new node1 */
    if (node1 == NULL) return newnode1(key1);

    /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
    if (key1 < node1->key1)
        node1->left1  = insert1(node1->left1, key1);
    else
        node1->right1 = insert1(node1->right1, key1);

    /* return the (unchanged) node1 pointer */
    return node1;
}

/* Given a non-empty binary search tree, return the node1 with minimum
   key1 value found in that tree. Note that the entire tree does not
   need to be searched. */
struct node1 * minValuenode1(struct node1* node1)
{
    struct node1* current = node1;

    /* loop down to find the left1most leaf */
    while (current->left1 != NULL)
        current = current->left1;

    return current;
}

/* Given a binary search tree and a key1, this function deletes the key1
   and returns the new root1 */
struct node1* deletenode1(struct node1* root1, int key1)
{
    // base case
    if (root1 == NULL) return root1;

    // If the key1 to be deleted is smaller than the root1's key1,
    // then it lies in left1 subtree
    if (key1 < root1->key1)
        root1->left1 = deletenode1(root1->left1, key1);

    // If the key1 to be deleted is greater than the root1's key1,
    // then it lies in right1 subtree
    else if (key1 > root1->key1)
        root1->right1 = deletenode1(root1->right1, key1);

    // if key1 is same as root1's key1, then This is the node1
    // to be deleted
    else
    {
        // node1 with only one child or no child
        if (root1->left1 == NULL)
        {
            struct node1 *temp1 = root1->right1;
            free(root1);
            return temp1;
        }
        else if (root1->right1 == NULL)
        {
            struct node1 *temp1 = root1->left1;
            free(root1);
            return temp1;
        }

        // node1 with two children: Get the inorder successor (smallest
        // in the right1 subtree)
        struct node1* temp1 = minValuenode1(root1->right1);

        // Copy the inorder successor's content to this node1
        root1->key1 = temp1->key1;

        // Delete the inorder successor
        root1->right1 = deletenode1(root1->right1, temp1->key1);
    }
    return root1;
}
struct bin_tree {
int data;
struct bin_tree * right, * left;
};
typedef struct bin_tree node;

void insert(node ** tree, int val)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
    }

}

void print_preorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        printf("%d\n",tree->data);
        print_preorder(tree->left);
        print_preorder(tree->right);
    }

}

void print_inorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        print_inorder(tree->left);
        printf("%d\n",tree->data);
        print_inorder(tree->right); // i want to print this as a tree
    }
}

void print_postorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        print_postorder(tree->left);
        print_postorder(tree->right);
        printf("%d\n",tree->data); 
    }
}

void deltree(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        deltree(tree->left);
        deltree(tree->right);
        free(tree);
    }
}

node* search(node ** tree, int val)
{
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->left), val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->right), val);
    }
    else if(val == (*tree)->data)
    {
        return *tree;
    }
}

void main()
{
    node *root;
    node *tmp;
    //int i;

    root = NULL;
    /* Inserting nodes into tree */
    insert(&root, 9);
    insert(&root, 4);
    insert(&root, 15);
    insert(&root, 6);
    insert(&root, 12);
    insert(&root, 17);
    insert(&root, 2);
    insert(&root, 0);
    /* Printing nodes of tree */
    printf("Pre Order Display\n");
    print_preorder(root); // i want to print this as a tree

    printf("In Order Display\n"); 
    print_inorder(root); // i want to print this as a tree

    printf("Post Order Display\n");
    print_postorder(root); // i want to print this as a tree
    /* Search node into tree */
    tmp = search(&root, 4);
    if (tmp)
    {
        printf("Searched node=%d\n", tmp->data);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Data Not found in tree.\n");
    }
 struct node1 *root1 = NULL;      // these
    root1 = insert1(root1, 50);// lines
    root1 = insert1(root1, 30);// delete a
    root1 = insert1(root1, 20);//node
    root1 = insert1(root1, 40);//and
    root1 = insert1(root1, 70);//then prints 
    root1 = insert1(root1, 60);//it 
    root1 = insert1(root1, 80);//
    root1 = deletenode1(root1, 50);    //
    inorder(root1);  // i want to print this as a tree
    /* Deleting all nodes of tree */
    deltree(root);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print graphical representation(I mean as tree using \ and `/`)?

Comment: kinda, if it is possible, thanks for the interest @kiranBiradar

Comment: You may know this already, but the usual way to print a binary tree is to (1) print the left subtree, (2) print the node you're at, (3) print the right subtree.  (And of course (1) and (3) are textbook examples of recursion.)

Comment: @SteveSummit I know the theory, but I don't know/don't have time to learn how to implement it

Comment: @kiranBiradar I guess you decided this is not worth your precious time?
because I see you deleted your comment.
Sorry for the inconvenience, I am just desperate.

Comment: @FrancescoBernouli Still trying. Struggling with spaces :D

Comment: Words can not describe how thankful I am
@kiranBiradar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you need to have `2^maxDepth` square box to plot the nodes properly.

*Root being plotted at `(0,(2^maxDepth)/2)` point and 
subsequent child nodes at `((1,(parent node position)/2), ((parent node positon)/2, 1)` position.*

**Consider below sample code.**

```
int maxDepth(node* node)  
{ 
   if (node==NULL)  
       return 0; 
   else 
   { 
       /* compute the depth of each subtree */
       int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left); 
       int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right); 

       /* use the larger one */
       if (lDepth > rDepth)  
           return(lDepth+1); 
       else return(rDepth+1); 
   } 
}

void drawTree(node *node)
{
   int maxdepth = maxDepth(node);
   int numSpace = pow(2,maxdepth)+1;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0;i < maxdepth;i++)
    {
        printGraph(node, numSpace, 1, i, 0);
        numSpace /=2;

        printf("\n");
     }

}

int printGraph(node *node, int numSpace,int isLeft, int expectedLevel, int currentLevel)
{


   int i = 0;

   if (node == NULL || currentLevel > expectedLevel)
    {
     for (i = 0;i<(numSpace)/2;i++) printf(" ");
     return -1;
    }

   if (expectedLevel == currentLevel)
   {
      for (i = 0;i<(numSpace)/2;i++) printf(" ");
      printf("%d", node->data);

   }
   else
   {

      printGraph(node->left, numSpace, 1, expectedLevel, currentLevel+1);

     for (i = 0;i<(numSpace)/2;i++) printf(" ");

        printGraph(node->right, (numSpace), 0, expectedLevel, currentLevel+1);


     return ret;

   }
}
```

And I call the `drawTree` from `main` as below.

```
void main()
{
    node *root;
    node *tmp;
    //int i;

    root = NULL;
    /* Inserting nodes into tree */
    insert(&root, 9);
    insert(&root, 4);
    insert(&root, 15);
    insert(&root, 6);
    insert(&root, 12);
    insert(&root, 17);
    insert(&root, 2);
insert(&root, 0);

insert(&root, 7);
insert(&root, 16);
    insert(&root, 18);

drawTree(root);

    deltree(root);
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
        9
    4        15
  2    6    12    17
 0      7      16  18
```

> Note: Now go ahead with adding edges to the nodes with the same
>   approach.

Comment: the code wont complie due to "incomplete struct node" , any fix?

Comment: Put the above code after `typedef struct bin_tree node;` line.